# Do NodeJS functions timeout if it takes too long ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, async-await

I have some third party APIs which run functions that take around 30 minutes to return results (they do some lengthy calculations ). 
Now if I use Nodejs to call such an API with an appropriate callback, will Nodejs by default wait for the 30 minutes for the function to return the result or will it timeout ? 
If it timesout, is there a way to increase the waiting time ?

Comment: How is the "third party API" integrated into the node environment? A HTTP request will surely time out.

Comment: The documentation of the API should state what an "appropriate callback" is. Yes, it will wait if that's how it should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default of Linux could use anything between 20s - 120s as timeout 
http://www.sekuda.com/overriding_the_default_linux_kernel_20_second_tcp_socket_connect_timeout

Depending on which request library you are using, you may have different syntax on setting the timeout. I personally like `request` a lot, Reference here https://github.com/request/request.

```
request.get('http://10.255.255.1', {timeout: 1500}, function(err) {
    console.log(err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT');
    // Set to `true` if the timeout was a connection timeout, `false` or
    // `undefined` otherwise.
    console.log(err.connect === true);
    process.exit(0);
});
```

I don't think NodeJS function itself would timeout though.

Answer (score 3):

I Assume that you are using `express` if you are using express you can add the below code to increase the waiting time.

```
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
server.timeout = 1000;
```

or else you can use the pure `http`

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
  }, 200);
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

server.timeout = 20;
```

Comment: I don't see what express had to do with "some third party APIs"?

Comment: As per the question Nodejs is used to call the third party API, So therefore, we have to handle the wait time at nodejs side to eliminate the timeout thing.

Comment: "call third party API" can mean anything. And no, we can't assume that the OP uses `request` for anything

Comment: @SuvethanNantha - Thanks. This was useful.